# How to insert base64 file into a specif tag using Python

Tags: python, base64

```
<book>
  <title>sponge bob</title>
  <author>Joe Doe</author>
  <file>Tbase</file>
</book>
```

I have 2 files, one is a xml and the other is a base64 file. I would like to know how to insert and replace the string"Tbase" with the content of the base64 file using python.

Comment: so you need to parse xml and replace the string Tbase with a base64 encoded string? How are you getting the string?

Comment: Tbase is a fixed string, base64 file is from "openssl enc -base64 -A" command.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to put the verbatim contents of the base64 file (still base64 encoded) into the XML file, in place of "Tbase"? If that's the case, you could just do something like:

```
xml = open("xmlfile.xml").read()
b64file = open("b64file.base64").read()
open("xmlfile.xml", "w").write(xml.replace("Tbase", b64file))
```

(If you're on Python 2.6 or later, you can do this a little bit cleaner using with statements, but that's another discussion.)

If you want to *decode* the base64 file first, and place the decoded contents into the XML file, then you'd replace `b64file` on the last line of the example above with `b64file.decode("base64")`.

Of course, doing simple text replacement, as above, opens you up to the problems you'll have if, say, the title or author contain "Tbase" as well. A better way would be to use an actual XML parsing library, like so:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import fromstring, tostring
xml = fromstring(open("xmlfile.xml").read())
xml.find("file").text = open("b64file.base64").read()
open("xmlfile.xml", "w").write(tostring(xml))
```

This sets the contents of the `<file>` tag to be the contents of the file `b64file.base64`, regardless of what its former contents were and regardless of whether "Tbase" appears elsewhere in the XML document.